# Problems with VirtualBox on Kali

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kali-linux

I installed VirtualBox on my Kali 4.6.0-kali1-amd64. VB launches but when I start a VM it gives me the following error:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

as root.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

I have attempted to fix this through multiple ways but I still cant get it to run. How can I fix this error so the I can run my VM?

////////

Removed VB.Downloaded the deb from the VB website. Using `apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)` returns the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64 E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64' E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64'
```

How can I fix this?

//////////////////
Update:

Fixed the headers issue by adding `deb http://mirror.nus.edu.sg/kali/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib` to my sources list. Reinstalled VB. Now I get:

```
RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)

The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful. Executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

may correct this. Make sure that you do not mix the OSE version and the PUEL version of VirtualBox.

where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime what: 4 VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver doesn't match the version of the user.
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a fault in the Virtual Box install log.

1. Remove VirtualBox and reboot the host.
2. Make sure everything is up to date.
3. Install the following packages.(sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r))
4. Get Virtual Box .deb or wget it from official source.

Hope this helps your problem :)

Comment: I tried this before. Did it again. I get the errors:
 `E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64' `
@MichaelMMeskhi

Comment: @fareewaybros : Don't make people read thru a growing trail of comments for the complete story on your problem. This info should be included in the body of your Q above. Good luck.

Comment: Problem maybe of your x32 and x64 architecture. Do this:

Comment: Update your system 'sudo apt-get update' next, 'sudo apt-get upgrade'

Comment: These solutions aren't very bold but usually weird problems are simply solved by updates. Try that and can you dump your 'uname -ax' output.

Comment: `Linux kali 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux` @MichaelMMeskhi

Comment: I've done 'dist-upgrade as well'

Comment: Try this right now and dump the output > '/sbin/vboxconfig'

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uVndtH5x ... Ran as root..

Comment: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log

Comment: `Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.`

Comment: Okay try this: Change the boot mode from 'UEFI' to 'UEFI with CSM' in VBox.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Okay first try this, 'sudo zypper install kernel-devel gcc' when that is complete run 'sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup'.

Comment: This should be the proper fix

Comment: Are Zypper packages available in Kali? Or would i have to find the deb?

Comment: Here: http://ftp.psu.ru/linux/kali/pool/main/z/zypper/

Comment: `Unpacking zypper (1.11.13-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zypper:
 zypper depends on libzypp; however:
  Package libzypp is not installed.
 zypper depends on zypper-common (>= 1.11.13-1); however:
  Package zypper-common is not installed.` Ughhhh

Comment: Havent found how to fix the zypper issue either... @MichaelMMeskhi

Comment: pluse-uno for patience and tech support. Hoping you can resolve the O.P.s problem! Good luck to all.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I am looking into it right now and will return to you with some solution :)

Comment: Still have not found a fix for this.. : ( @MichaelMMeskhi

Comment: Installing libzypp deleted my Gnome packages and left me with a GUIless Kali. Managed to get Gnome back.. no solution yet to Virtual Box problem.. @MichaelMMeskhi

Comment: Sorry for no response have been quite busy, I have Kali on my other laptop will try to install VBox and see if I run to anything similar to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the header and kernel issues I added `deb http://mirror.nus.edu.sg/kali/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib` to my sources list. Because I was installing the deb package of VB, I was getting:

```
RTR3InitEx failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)

The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful. Executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

may correct this. Make sure that you do not mix the OSE version and the PUEL version of VirtualBox.

where: supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime what: 4 VERR_VM_DRIVER_VERSION_MISMATCH (-1912) - The installed support driver doesn't match the version of the user.
```

I'm not sure what was causing this issue, but I fixed it by purging the deb installation and reinstalling VB with `apt-get install virtualbox`.